# How do I get the libipt library?

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to build RISCV and I need the library libipt but it is not in the Ubuntu packages. Tried to search for it:

```
apt-file search libipt
```

I found what I think to be the source files I need but I am a little leery of building it from an unkown source...

https://github.com/01org/processor-trace/tree/master/libipt

Is there a better place to get it that is more trustworthy?

It also seems like it was available in Ubuntu? (yackety and zesty within the libdevel package???):

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libipt-dev

But I am unsure of how to get it from there either.

What is the best way for me to get this library installed?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

I forgot to mention I am using 16.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/01org is official GitHub account of [Intel Open Source Center](https://01.org/), I think it is trustworthy.

FYI, The original 01org project page is [here](https://01.org/processor-trace-decoder-library)(**dead link**), web archive could be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140716044844/https://01.org/processor-trace-decoder-library). If you still don't trust the Github repo, the [download link in the web archive](https://01.org/sites/default/files/libipt-1.2.0.tar.gz) is still working at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the package that you want is libipt1, and can be installed from the command line by `sudo apt-get install libipt1`

This package is available for ubuntu Zesty and Yakkity, and the contents of the package are listed [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/libipt1/filelist)

To add this library to your installation, you will need to have the 'universe' repository enabled:  Start 'Software and updates' and ensure that the checkbox for Community-maintained free... if checked, as illustrated below

[image]

Or from the command line, issue `sudo add-apt-repository universe`.  In either case, you will need to `sudo apt-get update` after enabling the repository.

Comment: I get 'E: Unable to locate package libipt1'

Comment: @stephenmm  Do you have the "universe" software repository enabled?  I will append my answer with steps to make sure that it is available.

Comment: Yes, I have "universe" enabled.